# Modifying string in python snippet with an object

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error-999999

I am using arcpy to reproject a multidimensional raster, and I extracted the following snippet by running the tool in ArcGIS pro.  This is the snippet:

```
arcpy.management.ProjectRaster(input_file_path, output_file_path, "PROJCS['North_Pole_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',0.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',0.0],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',90.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "BILINEAR", "24966.9977186652 24966.9977186651", None, None, "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]", "NO_VERTICAL")
```

In this case the output resolution is 24966.9977186651 meters which is represented by `"24966.9977186652 24966.9977186651"` in the snippet.  I want to use arcpy to change the resolution based on an object such as:

```
out_res = 3000
```

I tried this:

```
   arcpy.management.ProjectRaster(in_path, out_path, "PROJCS['North_Pole_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',0.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',0.0],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',90.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "BILINEAR", str(out_res), None, None, "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]", "NO_VERTICAL")
```

but this is not valid and fails with:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.
Invalid cache raster dataset (CRF) with invalid/inconsistent definition.
Failed to execute (ProjectRaster).
```

Comment: in_path is the location of the multidimensional input raster and out_path is where to store the reprojected .crf file.

Comment: It is just the pathways on my hard drive is all so `in_path = r"C:\input_raster.tif"`and out_path = `r"C:\output_raster.tif"` or similar.  I can't type it in physically I need to use the object `out_res` in the script as the number will be changing depending on the resolution of `in_path`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the pathways, it has the `r`, it has to do with defining the resolution.

Comment: I also tried `str(out_res)`, with the same error

Comment: `out_coor_system` is taken directly from the geoprocessing toolbox python snippet, the first snipped I posted works just fine the exact same way.  The only difference between what works fine in the first one and what does not in the second one is how the resolution is defined

Comment: I have tried everything you are suggesting though.